# Named functions vs anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, scope

Sometimes I see these kind of examples coming by, and I am wondering whats the use of it.
I mean **this.methodA = function methodA(){}** why is this?

The only thing I can imagine is to use it without **this** when you have an issue with scoping. 
Anybody an idea?

```
function MyModule() {

  this.myMethod = function myMethod() {
    alert( 'my method' );
  };

  this.myOtherMethod = function myOtherMethod() {
    alert( 'my other method' );
  };

}
// Versus:
function MyModule() {

  this.myMethod = function () {
    alert( 'my method' );
  };

  this.myOtherMethod = function () {
    alert( 'my other method' );
  };

}
```

Comment: This can be used to simulate an environment with classes. Now you can run: var a = new MyModule(); a.myMethod(); . This will alert "my method".

Comment: Of course, but that doesn't give an explanation about the use of named functions versus anonymous functions.

Answer (score 3):

The main advantage of named function expressions over anonymous ones is that their name will show up in debuggers (stacktraces etc) which makes it a lot easier to figure out what is going on when something goes wrong.

A named function can also be called using its name from within its own scope. This is useful for creating recursive functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thats the only one?